# How to smooth-scroll to an anchor tag from another page in NextJS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, next.js

I have 2 pages in my NextJS (1 is Home and another is Leaderboard page). And I have a `navbar` as such:

```
<div className={styles.navItem}>
        <Link href="/">
          <a className={styles.navLinks} onClick={toggle}>
            Home
          </a>
        </Link>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.navItem} onClick={toggle}>
        <Link href="/">
          <a
            className={styles.navLinks}
            onClick={setTimeout((e) => {
              document.getElementById("about") &&
                document
                  .getElementById("about")
                  .scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "end" });
            }, 2000)}
          >
            About Us
          </a>
        </Link>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.navItem} onClick={toggle}>
        <Link href="/">
          <a
            className={styles.navLinks}
            onClick={setTimeout((e) => {
              document.getElementById("program") &&
                document
                  .getElementById("program")
                  .scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "end" });
            }, 2000)}
          >
            Program Overview
          </a>
        </Link>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.navItem}>
        <Link href="/leaderboard/">
          <a className={styles.navLinks} onClick={toggle}>
            Leaderboard
          </a>
        </Link>
      </div>
```

I thought that maybe by using a `setTimeout` delay it would, redirect me first to the homepage (when I click the `Link` tag) and then, after 2 seconds, it would smooth scroll me to the section I wanted to go to. But this produces an error `document is not defined` and when I reload the page, the page would smooth-scroll to `#program` after 2 seconds even without clicking on the tag. What am I doing wrong?

**ERROR (ON TERMINAL)**

```
error - components/main/Nav/MenuRight.js (18:23) @ Timeout.eval [as _onTimeout]
ReferenceError: document is not defined
  16 |         <Link href="/">
  17 |           <a
> 18 |             className={styles.navLinks}
     |                       ^
  19 |             onClick={() =>
  20 |               setTimeout((e) => {
  21 |                 document.getElementById("about") &&
```

Comment: try arrow funtion onClick={() => setTimeout((e)

Comment: @iamhuynq Right right I totally forgot about that haha thank you! But I'm still getting the `document is not defined` error, how can I handle that?

Comment: i have tested and it works, not sure what happened to you [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-tree-hlxjou?file=/pages/index.js)

Comment: @iamhuynq yeap it works, it runs. but in my terminal, i'm getting the error. I am updating my post to show the exact error I'm getting on my terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is you call `setTimeout` directly which is executed right away on the server (more specifically, NextJS does not have `window` and `document` objects on the server-side) that's why `document` is not available.

You should wrap it into a function like below and `onClick` will be only triggered once you click on that element

```
<div className={styles.navItem}>
        <Link href="/">
          <a className={styles.navLinks} onClick={toggle}>
            Home
          </a>
        </Link>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.navItem} onClick={toggle}>
        <Link href="/">
          <a
            className={styles.navLinks}
            onClick={(e) => {
             setTimeout(() => {
              document.getElementById("about") &&
                document
                  .getElementById("about")
                  .scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "end" 
              });
            }, 2000)
            }}
          >
            About Us
          </a>
        </Link>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.navItem} onClick={toggle}>
        <Link href="/">
          <a
            className={styles.navLinks}
            onClick={(e) => {
               setTimeout(() => {
                 document.getElementById("program") &&
                   document
                     .getElementById("program")
                     .scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "end" });
               }, 2000)
            }}
          >
            Program Overview
          </a>
        </Link>
      </div>
      <div className={styles.navItem}>
        <Link href="/leaderboard/">
          <a className={styles.navLinks} onClick={toggle}>
            Leaderboard
          </a>
        </Link>
      </div>
```

Comment: This will still produce the `document is not defined` error wouldnt it?

Comment: you're getting the same error? @Owenn

Comment: Oh my bad, turns out I put `(e)` in the wrong place. It works perfectly thank you!